# How can I selectively print scripts to the footer of certain admin pages?

Tags: scripts, footer

I'm using [`admin_footer-{$hook_suffix}`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/admin_footer-%7B%24hook_suffix%7D) to selectively print scripts on the new post page and comments page. This hook is depreciated in 3.1.

I [see](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/admin_print_scripts-%7B%24hook_suffix%7D?version=3.1&file=wp-admin/admin-header.php) there's an `admin_print_scripts-{$hook_suffix}` but this does not print to the footer, rather to the header before any jQuery or other stuff is loaded.

How can I selectively print scripts to the footer of certain admin pages?

Comment: Use `wp_enqueue_script` inside the function you hook on and set the `in_footer` parameter to true, and your script will get output in the footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an `in_footer` parameter that you can pass to wp_enqueue_scripts - does that work?

I would hook to `admin_enqueue_scripts`, check the $page for location, and enqueue your script there, with 'in_footer' as true.

Example:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_script' );

function enqueue_my_script( $page ) {
    if ($page !== 'edit.php') return;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', 'http://path/to/my/local/script', null, null, true );
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of checking $page for location?

Comment: Thank you. I did not know $page was a synonym for the current page suffix.

Comment: Um, yeah, guess I took a shorthand there. There's also the global variable $pagenow which also holds the same information, in case you need to check it where its not being explicitly passed as the context of a hook.

Comment: There appears to be no $page variable (declared globally or otherwise) in my MU 2.9. $pagenow global worked out however, so thanks for including.

Answer (score 5):

There is also another way to achieve this which allows you to build more dynamic scripts using the [`admin_footer`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_footer) hook,

```
    add_action('in_admin_footer', 'my_custom_admin_page');
    function my_custom_admin_page () {  
      //you can check if this is the right page
      $screen = get_current_screen();  
      if('post'== $screen->base && 'my-custom-post' == $screen->id){ 
      ?>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(document).ready( function(){ 
           //check something 
        }); 
      </script>
      <?php 
      }
    }
```

This method allows you to build a dynamic script to inject into the admin page.

Comment: Thank you man!!